# Increment column in model with Ajax in ruby on rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm new in rails and i have trouble incrementing an integer column (quantity) for the sales model in a my rails app. Users can increment quantity of a product in the app using buttons like this one:

**Sales/show.html.erb**

```
 <tbody>
 <% @ven_pros.each {|s| %>
                  <tr>

                    <td><%= link_to ' + ', "/sale_products/#{params[:id]}/increment/#{s.id};", class: "btn btn-md btn-primary" %></td>

                  </tr>

                <% } %>
 </tbody>
```

this is my route for it

**routes.rb**

```
get   'sale_products/:id/increment/:product_id' , to: 'sale_products#increment'
```

and this is my action for the incrementing

**sale_products_controller.rb**

```
  def increment
@pro = SaleProduct.find(params[:product_id])
@pro.increment!(:quantity)

@pro.save!
respond_to do |format|
  format.html { redirect_to sale_url(params[:id]), notice: 'Quantity was successfully increment.' }
  format.json { head :no_content }
end
end
```

that work for me but this load the page each time the user wants to increment quantity

how can't i do it using ajax/javascript

Answer (score 0):

Use `remote: true` option for `link_to`:

```
<%= link_to ' + ', "/sale_products/#{params[:id]}/increment/#{s.id};", class: "btn btn-md btn-primary", remote: true %>
```

See how it works: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#built-in-helpers

To make it work as expected the `application.js` file should include Rails UJS file. If you built your app from scratch with standard `rails new` command it should be there already. Otherwise, you could add it manually:

```
//= require rails-ujs
```

**UPDATE:**

If you want not just to send an AJAX-request, but receive a response from the server and update some part of your page, then writing your custom JS handler is inevitable. By clicking your link that handler will initiate a request, parse the response and update data on the page.

Using JQuery it can be done this way for example:

1. Add a special class to your link for catching clicks on it:

   ```
   <%= link_to ' + ', '#', data: { url: "/sale_products/#{params[:id]}/increment/#{s.id}" }, class: "btn btn-md btn-primary incrementor" %></td>
   ```
2. Make sure your controller action responds with data you want to show on the page:

   ```
   format.json { render json: { quantity: @pro.quantity } }
   ```
3. Finally, add that JS code snippet to your JS:

   ```
   $(function() {
     $(document).on('click', '.incrementor', function(e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       var $this = $(this);
       var url = $this.data('url');

       $.ajax({
         url: url,
         type: 'GET',
         beforeSend: function(xhr) {xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'))}

       }).done(function(data) {
         if (data.quantity) {
           $('.quantity-updated').html(data.quantity);
         }
       });
     });
   });
   ```

   What this code does: when a link with class `incrementor` is clicked it fetches URL from HTML-element's `url` data attribute, sends a GET request to that URL, parses the response and if it has `quantity` key replaces content of HTML-element with class `quantity-updated` with new quantity. (`quantity-updated` is given just for illustration; for sure you need to insert your own method of finding an element to update.)

Comment: thanks for your response, i have to add remote: true ? without any javascript code !?

Comment: Correct, no extra JS code is necessary for your link. But you have to include Rails UJS file into your ```application.js```. If you built your app from scratch with standard ```rails new``` command it should be there. Otherwise, you could add it manually: ```//= require rails-ujs```

Comment: thanks that works, the problem now is that the user can't see the the new value, he should have reload the page !!!!!

Comment: why not making a new controller method and a `js.erb` to render a partial for making changes in the view to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing would be making a remote call

`<%= link_to ' + ', "/sale_products/#{params[:id]}/increment/#{s.id};", class: "btn btn-md btn-primary", remote: true %>`

then in the controller in your increment method:

```
def increment
  @pro = SaleProduct.find(params[:product_id])
  @pro.increment!(:quantity)
end
```

create a file to handle jquery and it should have to be of the same name as the method.

file would be : 
`increment.js.erb`

content of this file:

```
$('.quantity-updated').html('<%= @pro.quantity %>');
```

and you're done